# Height of child div overflows parent container

Tags: css, layout, html

In the example, 
http://fiddle.jshell.net/dwuZp/15/

What is the reason for "icons" div to overflows "logoTimeAndIcons" parent div height?

*If you change it to 50% height you will be able to see the problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icons object is set to be 100% the height of the parent object (which is 400px in this case).  If you place a 200px object in a 200px parent, this makes sense.  The two floating divs above (combined with *clear: both* applied to #icons), leads this div to flowing down past the end of its parent div.  This is expected and normal behavior.  Objects can (and often do) flow out of their parent containers.  The *overflow* css-attribute will help manage this.

As for what to do if you are having issues on this, either:

1. **Resize** #icons to be a smaller height (in this case 100px)
2. or, set *overflow: hidden* on #logoTimeAndIcons to hide the overflowing div.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Is there anyway i can tell #icons that he have 100px on top but still take 100% of the rest?

Comment: You can use CSS3 calc(100% - 100px), but it has minimal browser support at this point.  I would suggest specifying your height directly on the child, 100px instead of 100%.  There's little loss to this approach and you'll guarantee everything is in working order.

Comment: css3 is out of the scope, I will try to add additional inner div or using top-margin property, Thank you!